# Getting html content for buttons using an event handler wrapper

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I'm using a wrapper to attach event handlers to some buttons on a page. Using the following code I can get the button ID when I clicl each of the buttons. However, I need to get the content of the pre tags and concatenate the content of the two divs to create a command when each of the buttons are clicked.

Could somebody please help.

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

wrapper.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
var parent=event.target.parentElement;

console.log(parent.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML);


  const isButton = event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON';
  if (!isButton) {
    return;
  }
  
})
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

    <div class="command">
        <p>description 1</p>
        <div>
            <pre><div>kubectl&nbsp;</div><div>create cluster</div></pre>
        </div>
        <button id="button1" class="demo-button-small">Run</button>
    </div>

    <div class="command">
        <p>description 2</p>
        <div>
            <pre><div>kubectl&nbsp;</div><div>delete cluster</div></pre>
        </div>
        <button id="button2" class="demo-button-small">Run</button>
    </div>

    <div class="command">
        <p>description 3</p>
        <div>
            <pre><div>kubectl&nbsp;</div><div>list cluster</div></pre>
        </div>
        <button id="button3" class="demo-button-small">Run</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.closest()` to find the containg DIV, then use `.querySelector()` to find the `<pre>` tag inside that and get its `innerText`.

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

wrapper.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const isButton = event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON';
  if (!isButton) {
    return;
  }
  const div = event.target.closest("div.command");
  if (div) {
    const pre = div.querySelector("pre");
    if (pre) {
      console.log(pre.innerText);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div class="command">
    <p>description 1</p>
    <div>
      <pre><div>kubectl&nbsp;</div><div>create cluster</div></pre>
    </div>
    <button id="button1" class="demo-button-small">Run</button>
  </div>

  <div class="command">
    <p>description 2</p>
    <div>
      <pre><div>kubectl&nbsp;</div><div>delete cluster</div></pre>
    </div>
    <button id="button2" class="demo-button-small">Run</button>
  </div>

  <div class="command">
    <p>description 3</p>
    <div>
      <pre><div>kubectl&nbsp;</div><div>list cluster</div></pre>
    </div>
    <button id="button3" class="demo-button-small">Run</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get button Id, try this

```
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

wrapper.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const isButton = event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON';
  if (!isButton) {
    return;
  }
  let button = document.getElementById(event.target.id)
  text = button.parentNode.children[1].children[0].innerHTML
  console.log(text)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

get the parent element and then get the pre tag within the parent

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

wrapper.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
var parent=event.target.parentElement;

console.log(parent.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML);


  const isButton = event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON';
  if (!isButton) {
    return;
  }
  
})
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

    <div class="command">
        <p>description 1</p>
        <div>
            <pre><div>kubectl&nbsp;</div><div>create cluster</div></pre>
        </div>
        <button id="button1" class="demo-button-small">Run</button>
    </div>

    <div class="command">
        <p>description 2</p>
        <div>
            <pre><div>kubectl&nbsp;</div><div>delete cluster</div></pre>
        </div>
        <button id="button2" class="demo-button-small">Run</button>
    </div>

    <div class="command">
        <p>description 3</p>
        <div>
            <pre><div>kubectl&nbsp;</div><div>list cluster</div></pre>
        </div>
        <button id="button3" class="demo-button-small">Run</button>
    </div>

</div>
```